# How do I query Google Drive for id of a folder with known name in root folder (Google Drive SDK for iPhone)?

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

With query

`GTLQueryDrive *queryFilesList = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@"root"];`

I get everything in root folder: files and folders.  Sure, I can look for folder in `GTLDriveChildList` returned. But root folder can have thousands items, and I need only one of them. I tried narrow search. Comments in `GTLQueryDrive.h` say it's possible. I've tried 
`queryFilesList.q =  @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";`

to query only folders or 
`queryFilesList.q =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"title='%@'", folderName];` 
to query all items by name. Both queries return empty lists. *Double checked: folder I look for really exists.*

I've tried

```
GTLQueryDrive *queryFilesList = [GTLQueryDrive queryForFilesList];
```

It works well with

```
queryFilesList.q =  @"mimeType='audio/x-aiff'";
```

But returns empty list if I try to query only folders with

```
queryFilesList.q =  @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7):

I am selfish idiot!

```
GTLQueryDrive *queryFilesList = [GTLQueryDrive queryForChildrenListWithFolderId:@"root"];
queryFilesList.q = @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'";
```

works just fine, but it sees ONLY folders created with this app! That was my problem. To be exact you may use this query:

```
queryFilesList.q = @"mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder' and 'root' in parents and trashed=false";
```

`trashed=false` is important if you don't want trashed items to be found.

Comment: how did you get it to show you all files, not just those created by the current app?

Comment: Ah, the app needs to use kGTLAuthScopeDrive rather than kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile.

Comment: @pstoppani, where are you adjusting that constant?  I'm not using either of those anywhere during my authorization.  can you add to your answer with what seems like a very important detail?

Comment: @tarabyte Swift version is as follows:                                                     private func createAuthController() -> GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch {

        return GTMOAuth2ViewControllerTouch(
            scope: kGTLAuthScopeDriveFile,
            clientID: Constants.kClientID,
            clientSecret: nil,
            keychainItemName: Constants.kKeychainItemName,
            delegate: self,
            finishedSelector: #selector(ViewController.viewController(_:finishedWithAuth:error:))
        )
    }